# How do I put variable from edittext to html?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent

I want my activity to create a html file and within that file named temp.html 
There. There will be a particular starting and ending tag.
My texts from edittext will be loaded in between starting and ending tag, [(div.. text from edittext here (/div] and for a new line it will automatically add a (br tag. 
Note: The file doesn't exist and will override if it does. I cannot upload image as I am a new user.

Comment: What is your question??? Do you want us to do it?

Comment: Indeed. I see no question. And what is your problem doing so? Please show the code you have already.

Comment: I want to create a text file which currently have some some html tags. Everything I write will save in between two tags.